# Python how to use variable in sp.call with flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to generate a certificate by requesting data from the web using flask and python.

```
        sp.call([
        'openssl', 'req', 
        '-new', 
        '-key', 'certs_out/certs/key_name.key', 
        '-out', 'certs_out/certs/csr_name.csr', 
        '-subj', '/C=%s/L=%s/O=%s/CN=%s', 
        '-addext', 'subjectAltName = DNS:%s'
        ],(C,L,O,CN,SAN))
```

But I am getting an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2213, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/application/project/certificate-home/cert.py", line 27, in create
    sp.call([
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 345, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 780, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

Help with the correct substitution of variables %s in sp.call.

Comment: Please provide the details of the `error` and any error text like full trace back, message windows etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with os.system

```
os.system("openssl req -new -key certs_out/certs/key_name.key -out certs_out/certs/csr_name.csr -subj \"/C=%s/L=%s/O=%s/CN=%s\" -addext \"subjectAltName = DNS:%s\"" % (C, L, O, CN, SAN))
```